# Clear unused devices at /devices Solaries 10

Tags: unix, solaris, solaris-10

When i use command format the output is:

AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:

```
   0. c0d0 <DEFAULT cyl 1302 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
      /pci@0,0/pci-ide@7,1/ide@0/cmdk@0,0
   1. c2t0d0 <DEFAULT cyl 1020 alt 2 hd 64 sec 32>
      /pci@0,0/pci15ad,1976@10/sd@0,0
```

But after searching in /dev/dsk $ /dev/rdsk using ls i found:

```
bash-3.00# ls

c0d0p0     c0d0s11    c0d0s5     c1t0d0p3   c1t0d0s14  c1t0d0s8   c2t0d0s1   c2t0d0s3
c0d0p1     c0d0s12    c0d0s6     c1t0d0p4   c1t0d0s15  c1t0d0s9   c2t0d0s10  c2t0d0s4
c0d0p2     c0d0s13    c0d0s7     c1t0d0s0   c1t0d0s2   c2t0d0p0   c2t0d0s11  c2t0d0s5
c0d0p3     c0d0s14    c0d0s8     c1t0d0s1   c1t0d0s3   c2t0d0p1   c2t0d0s12  c2t0d0s6
c0d0p4     c0d0s15    c0d0s9     c1t0d0s10  c1t0d0s4   c2t0d0p2   c2t0d0s13  c2t0d0s7
c0d0s0     c0d0s2     c1t0d0p0   c1t0d0s11  c1t0d0s5   c2t0d0p3   c2t0d0s14  c2t0d0s8
c0d0s1     c0d0s3     c1t0d0p1   c1t0d0s12  c1t0d0s6   c2t0d0p4   c2t0d0s15  c2t0d0s9
c0d0s10    c0d0s4     c1t0d0p2   c1t0d0s13  c1t0d0s7   c2t0d0s0   c2t0d0s2
```

### Question 1

I know that `c0d0p0` is fdisk partitions because i'm on x86 system not spark but still i don't understand why it appeared even though i never used fdisk?

### Question 2

As you saw at format output i only have c0d0 [IDE] and c2t0d0 [SCSI] but i don't have c1t0d0s0 ?!! i even used devfsadm -C and still it exists.

i used format /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0 and told me No disk found!

I dont understand what is this exactly and using ls -l is sure points on a device file at /device

```
bash-3.00# ls -l c1t0d0s0

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          52 Nov 29  2012 c1t0d0s0 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@7,1/ide@1/sd@0,0:a,raw
```

so can you please tell me what is that exactly and how can i remove it?

Answer (score 1):

1: No need to use fdisk to get `c0d0p0`, the OS provision every possible entry (partition/slice) regardless of whether they actually exist or not.

2: This device is likely not handled by format, might a CD/DVD drive or a remote device (USB key, drive, ...)